# choosing $β_0$ and $β_1$ to minimize the residual sum of squares

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, sums-of-squares

I'm reading a book called [An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461471370), and I have a question in regards to the material inside.

I understand that we can find the residual sum of squares by finding the difference between the $i^\text{th}$ observed response value and the $i^\text{th}$ response value that is predicted by our model. In other words the sum of $(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$ for every sample data point where $\hat{y}_i$ is the expected response from our model using constants $β_0$ and $β_1$. What I cannot understand is how to use calculus to find the minimizers $β_0$(this makes sense actually) and $β_1$ for the model. I was told that to come up with this equation that finds the minimizers we needed to find the minima of the RSS function using partial derivatives where both $β_0$ and $β_1$. I however have no clue how to do this, I am hoping that someone more experience could write it out for me. In the meantime I am going over partial derivatives to better grasp this.

Here is a screenshot of the formula given in the book to find the minimizers:

[image: screenshot of the formula given in the book to find the minimizers]

Comment: The key is that RSS is a quadratic function, and it has second-order partial derivatives. You can first show it is a convex function of $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$, and that therefor any local optimum will be the global minimum of RSS. You then have to find the values $(\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1)$ that solve $\frac{\partial RSS}{\beta_0}=\frac{\partial RSS}{\beta_1}=0$.

Comment: Wikipedia has [a derivation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Derivation_of_simple_regression_estimators) of this.

Comment: great thank you!

Also is this related to gradient descent?

Comment: @user3880985 Not really. You could use gradient descent to find the best model coefficients, but here there's a closed-form solution instead.